# depth of 2 leaves in an AVL tree

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

How's that an AVL tree can have **leaves** that differ in their depth by a value **higher** then 1?
I mean, an AVL is defined as for every two leaves x,y:
|x.depth - y.depth| <= 1

So how can I build an AVL that **|x.depth - y.depth| > 1** ?

Help much appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

turned out the question is really stupid.
figured out by a friend's help.

my mistake was looking at the "depth paths" lengths though I had only to watch what is going on beneath every single node. without looking above the node.
means, as long as every node has difference of "1" in the height of its sub-trees, it's ok.

here I attach an example, to be sure that the AVL is balanced, go from the bottom towards AVL's root and compare every right and left sub-trees of every node. you will be convinced that it's a balanced AVL tree. (although         |leaf24.depth-leaf10.depth| > 1 ; |leaf24.depth-leaf10.depth|=2)!!

***Attached example:***
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEHsU.png